# HttpServletResponseWrapper not working for setting headers

Tags: java, http, web.xml

I'm trying to use a filter to allow cross-origin access to my server methods, so what I'm doing is adding a header in a filter. I read somewhere that I should use HttpServletResponseWrapper so I can add headers before they're sent to the client, but I can't make it work. This is what I've tried:

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     version="2.5"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >    

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.novatronic.web.filter.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**This is the url**: http://localhost:8080/hbo-web/api/public/login

**This is my doFilter method:**

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
  HboResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HboResponseWrapper(response);
  responseWrapper.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:43040");
  responseWrapper.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE");
  responseWrapper.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
  responseWrapper.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

  responseWrapper.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Cache-Control, Host, Pragma, Referer, User-Agent");
  filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, responseWrapper);
}
```

**My wrapper:**

```
package com.novatronic.web.util;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

public class HboResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

  public HboResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
  {
    super(httpServletResponse);
  }

}
```

Yet I get the CORS error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/hbo-web/api/public/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:43040' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Don't know why it's not working, but if all you need is for the filter to set predefined headers, you don't need a wrapper. Just call those `addHeader()` methods on `response`. You use wrappers if you need to *intercept* (filter/monitor) response values.

Comment: @Andreas should I do that after or before the doFilter call?

Comment: You must set values before `doFilter()` call, because response might be committed upon return, so you can't do it after.